# Unknown custom element: <svgIcon>

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I am running a nuxt app and testing with vue-test-utils and jest.

The issue I get is that certain modules that are installed but certain components like `<nuxt-link> or  <svg-icon>` are throwing warnings.

```
Unknown custom element: <svg-icon>
```

These are installed by nuxt or on top so am unsure of how to get rid of them. Any help would be appreciated.

**Solution**

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(Header, {
    stubs: ["svg-icon", "nuxt-link"]
});
```

Comment: Mock/stub those guilty components

Comment: Thanks, it works - code added - a bit of a pain though better to have verbose output.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the question works, but does not account for all use cases.

Please note, that this answer is tailored to vue3 and vue test-utils v2.

**Use case 1:**
I don't need to access inner elements of the NuxtLink or Svg.
=> Stubbing is a good option, so this leads to a solution like the one provided inside the question:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(Header, {
  props,
  global: {
    stubs: {
      nuxt-link: true,
      svg-icon: true,
    },
  },
});
```

**Use case 2:**
I want to access inner elements of the NuxtLink for some reasons.
=> Stubbing won't work, instead we can define a custom component in the test file:

Note: We still need to list NuxtLink in the stubs and set it to false:

```
wrapper = shallowMount(Header, {
  props,
  global: {
    stubs: {
      nuxt-link: false,
      svg-icon: true,
    },
    components: {
      nuxt-link: {
        template: '<a><slot/></a>',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

What this does is replacing the NuxtLink with the template you define for it. Used html elements inside are kept, the attributes (like classes or the "to" attribute) are automatically applied.

This means, given the following usage of NuxtLink

```
<nuxt-link
  to="www.example.com"
  class="item-class"
><div>ItemContent</div></nuxt-link>
```

, the output of wrapper.html will then be

```
<a to="www.example.com" class="item-class"><div>ItemContent</div></a>
```